# How to call a derived class method from a base class method within the constructor of base

Tags: c++, class, virtual, radix

I am wondering if it is possible to call a derived class´ function from within a function called by the base constructor (shouldn´t it already be created when the code in the brackets are executed?)

```
#pragma once
class ClassA
{
public:
 ClassA(void);
 virtual ~ClassA(void);

 void Init();

protected:
 short m_a;
 short m_b;

 virtual void SetNumbers(short s);
};

include "ClassA.h"
#include <iostream>


ClassA::ClassA(void) : m_a(0), m_b(0)
{
Init();
}


ClassA::~ClassA(void)
{
}

void ClassA::SetNumbers(short s)
{
 std::cout << "In ClassA::SetNumbers()\n";
 m_a = s;
 m_b = s;
}

void ClassA::Init()
{
 this->SetNumbers(2);
}
```

---

```
#pragma once
#include "ClassA.h"
class ClassB : public ClassA
{
public:
 ClassB(void);
 virtual ~ClassB(void);

 virtual void SetNumbers(short);

 int x;
};

#include "ClassB.h"
#include <iostream>


ClassB::ClassB(void)
{
}


ClassB::~ClassB(void)
{
}

void ClassB::SetNumbers(short s)
{
 std::cout << "In ClassB::SetNumbers()\n";

 m_a = ++s;
 m_b = s;

 ClassA::SetNumbers(s);
}
```

Any suggestions how to do it?...

Thank You in advance :)...

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507100/order-of-destruction-using-virtual/3507226#3507226) about why you can't call into a derived class from a base class' constructor or destructor.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling virtual functions inside constructors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962132/calling-virtual-functions-inside-constructors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  All parts of B (starting with A, as it's base) are constructed before B's constructor is called.  So, by the time `SetNumbers` is called, no part of B (except for the A part) has been constructed --- and that may include the v-table, so there's no way to know where that call is going to go.

Of course, there is a simple solution to this:  Call B::SetNumber() from within B's constructor (That is, after all, the purpose of B's constructor)

Comment: well... this is just an simple example for a server program i was writing... but i guess i have to rethink the automatic call of Init()...

Comment: @Incubbus: A lot of people who ask that question come from languages, like ObjectiveC, which don't have ctors, and where the idiom you describe in the norm -- and wonder why the idiom is broken in C++.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this for the simple logical reason that while the base class is being constructed, the derived class hasn't even begun to be constructed. You can't call a member function on an object that doesn't exist (yet).

In practice, even if you managed to call `SetNumbers` and assign to the member variables of the derived class before they were initialized they would surely be overwritten when they finally get initialized. I admit it's a bit pointless to reason about this as we would be well outside defined behaivour.

Answer (score 1):

No, sorry. :(  It might compile in one or two C++ compilers, but it's not recommended.  From the [C++ FAQ Lite section 10.7](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.7):

> [10.7] Should you use the this pointer
> in the constructor?
>
> [...snip...]
>
> Here is something that never works:
> **the {body} of a constructor (or a
> function called from the constructor)
> cannot get down to a derived class by
> calling a virtual member function that
> is overridden in the derived class.** If
> your goal was to get to the overridden
> function in the derived class, you
> won't get what you want. Note that you
> won't get to the override in the
> derived class independent of how you
> call the virtual member function:
> explicitly using the this pointer
> (e.g., this->method()), implicitly
> using the this pointer (e.g.,
> method()), or even calling some other
> function that calls the virtual member
> function on your this object. The
> bottom line is this: **even if the
> caller is constructing an object of a
> derived class, during the constructor
> of the base class, your object is not
> yet of that derived class.** You have
> been warned.

NOTE: Emphasis mine.

More details at the link

Answer (score 1):

The only time you can do this is when something is derived from a template that is parameterised by itself:

```
template<typename T> class base
{
  T* down_cast() throw()
  {
    return static_cast<Derived*>(this);
  }
  const T* down_cast() const throw()
  {
    return static_cast<const Derived*>(this);
  }
public:
  base()
  {
    down_cast()->doSomething();
  }
 /* … */
};

class derived : private base<derived>
{
public:
  void doSomething()
  {
  }
};
```

Note that `doSomething` is public and not virtual.

We can static_cast to derived, because it's known that derived is the derived type.

Deriving something from a base parameterised by itself is a strange thing to be doing at the best of times. It's said that when the ATL team in microsoft used it they asked the C++ compiler team if it was valid and nobody was sure, though it is valid because template construction depends on names as follows:

First the template is available, but not used in a class. Then, the name `derived` available. Then it instantiates the layout of `base<derived>` — this requires knowledge of the member variables and virtual functions, as long as none of that depends upon knowledge of `derived`’s layout (pointers and references are fine) this will all go okay. Then it will create the layout of `derived`, and finally it will create `derived`’s member functions, which may include creating member functions for `base<derived>`. So as long as `base<derived>` doesn’t contain a derived member variable (base classes can never contain a member variable of a type derived from themselves) or a virtual function that requires knowledge of derived’s layout we can indeed do the dicey-looking piece of inheritance above.

This includes being able to call non-virtual public members of `derived` from `base` during construction, because it's already part of base. There are strong limitations on this. In particular, if `doSomething()` depends on anything constructed in `derived`'s constructor it won't work as `derived` hasn't been constructed yet.

Now, is this actually a good idea? No.

Answer (score 0):

A simple design solution is to use **aggregation** instead of **inheritance**.

Comment: That would merely make what he is doing impossible.  It would, however, not solve his problem (since his design is based on inheritance)

Comment: That's why I'm saying it's a *design* alternative.

Comment: Besides, what he's trying to do is impossible anyway.

Comment: His current design compiles, but fails at run-time.  Your solution merely makes it fail at compile time.  However, except for this one hurdle, his overall task is suited for inheritance.  Changing the entire design to aggregation, just to solve this problem is pointless extra work.

Comment: My solution is to avoid inheritance if possible, and *never* use `protected` data members. I think we are arguing about different things.